# How to add fade in effect to following js script?

Tags: javascript, jquery, fadein

I have a js script that shows loading image and than loads content into `#content div`.
It works fine, but I cant figure out how to make it so it fades in content once it is loaded?

```
function viewHome(){
    $('#woodheader').load("inc/home.php");
    $('#content').html('<span class="loader">Loading..&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<img class="loaderimg" src="images/ajax_loader.gif"/></span>').load("inc/home.php");
}
```

For example when `.load("inc/home.php");` finishes, I would like to fade in the content of **inc/home.php** file with duration of 3 seconds. How can I do it?

Comment: You are calling `.load("inc/home.php")` on two separate elements.  Is that intentional?  Do you want the fade effect on both elements?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
function viewHome() {
    $('#woodheader').load("inc/home.php");
    var content = $('#content');
    content.html('<span class="loader">Loading..&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;" +
        "<img class="loaderimg" src="images/ajax_loader.gif"/></span>');
    content.load("inc/home.php", function () {
        content.hide().fadeIn(3000);
    });
}
```

Comment: As a matter of personal preference I like to prepend `$` onto variables that are jQuery objects. Like `var $content = $('#content');` - upvoted for the best answer still.

Comment: A sort of hungarian notation nouveau.  It's probably a good practice, but I have yet to adopt it personally...  We'll see.  :-)

Answer (score 1):

Use opacity:0 from css (and filter:alpha(opacity=0) for ie) to #content

and then add $("#content").fadeIn(duration) to your function

Comment: tried it, doesn't show any content at all, I guess opacity stays 0 for content div. I dont think I need to set opacity to 0 for content, could it be another div in inc/home.php file maybe?

Comment: i read it wrong, you put it on the div you are loading the html into :)

Answer (score 0):

with jquery put your code into this

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // put jquery fade call in here
});
```

Use the jquery function

```
$("#element").fadeIn(350);
```

Comment: yeh, but the thing is I dont know how to call jquery "fade". once I put my code in $(document) how do I add fade in function?